# Apps built using Intel XDK

Tags: intel-xdk

I am looking for a showcase/examples of mobile applications built with Intel XDK. Other than Intel, do you know any mainstream/popular organizations who used Intel XDK to make apps on different platforms? I have tried Google and Intel forums but to no avail.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a long time coming! App showcase for Intel XDK is finally here!

https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk-projects

Answer (score 5):

Here are two examples that have publicly said they used the Intel XDK to produce the following apps:

http://halfgeekstudios.wordpress.com/2014/02/10/re-launched-ninja-legacy-using-intels-crosswalk-compiler/

http://secondfiction.com/games/atomic-robo-violent-science/

Over a 1,000 apps are currently using the Intel XDK in Google Play, over 100 of those use Crosswalk Project. There are several Windows and Apple applications also. Intel employees cannot disclose users or any major corporations we are working with unless we have signed consent from those parties.

If you suspect that any application uses the Intel XDK, you can look for any of the frameworks included with the Intel XDK builds in the source code.

I will pass on that you would like a Testimonial or Showcase page on our website. :)

Update - 5/8/2014:
In version 0876, you will notice we now have a way for Intel to ask permission to use applications built with the Intel XDK in HTML5 promotional material. When a user builds an application, they can now check a permissions box at the bottom of the Build Success dialog. Just wanted to update that we are making an effort towards your request to share apps built using the Intel XDK. 
[image: Permission checkbox to allow Intel to use application in HTML5 promotional material]

Comment: Thanks mnementh! Those are really good examples. I was hoping Intel XDK would have a similar page to Appcelerator's App Showcase [link](http://www.appcelerator.com/customers/app-showcase/)

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response!